# Does an online trader affect futures prices as a real (physical) trader?

Tags: futures, commodities, online-trading, online-brokerage

When I buy a future contract (1 contract), will I affect the price and volume and the other numbers, the same as a physical trader (if he buys 1 contract), Will the trade volume increased by two or the physical commodity traders are separated from other traders (who close the position before liquidation date) ?

Comment: Why would they not affect the price and volume? What is a physical trader? I thought all trading was now done online (as opposed to 15 years ago when there were actual stock exchanges where people would go and shout at each other)

Comment: @user253751 I meant the merchant (who wants the underlying commodity in real)

Comment: well generally price yes, volume no, because you are trying to end up with zero net volume in the end aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

If you buy one futures contract, the trade volume of the futures contract goes up by one. There is no direct trade in the physical market to match.

However, let's say that you buy 10x futures contracts on a commodity like corn then there are bushels of corn in existence, and you hold to physical delivery. Some people on the other end of those contracts may not have enough bushels of corn to send to you and then may have to go to the phsyical market in order not to default on their delivery to you. So that will likely drive trading in the physical market.

But, if you close all your open futures contract positions before the delivery, then maybe no physical corn will ever change hands, because no one owes you corn anymore.

So, futures contract trading *can* have an effect on the phsyical market, but it's indirect.